# Force download a folder by using a link in javascript

Tags: javascript

These code works for download a html file,but i need to download a folder please help to solve this.

```
             var downloadurl = path+'?_=1&forceDownload=true'
             var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader',
             iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameID);
             if (iframe === null) {
             iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
             iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
             iframe.style.display = 'none';
             document.body.appendChild(iframe);
              }
             iframe.src = downloadurl;
```

Comment: in that case you need to create a zip of that folder